# new flutter project in vscode has error

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

when i create a new flutter project in vscode it will immediately shows an error in the main.dart file and gives a gradle error when trying to debug.

shown here:  [main.dart error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CeKb.png)

"compiler message: lib/main.dart:68:19: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given."

I've reinstalled dart and flutter plugins.  updated the java install. 
in debug console i get this:
[debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH9WP.png)

added output of  flutter doctor -v 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi3Jp.png)

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v`.

Comment: i can run flutter doctor regularly but if i try to use -v  in the vscode command palette i get no commands matching.  in regular terminal window it shows "bash: flutter: command not found".  I did set the path in my bash_profile file.

Comment: Try `. ~/.bash_profile` before `flutter doctor -v` (notice the `. ` at the beginning of the command)

Comment: i ran " . ~/.bash_profile " in terminal and uploaded an image of the results .  i still get no commands matching when using the vscode command palette.

Comment: What is the output of `flutter analyze` in the terminal? You probably neec to restart your machine to have the path setting activated. I don't lnow VSCode but it looks like the issue is VSCode config.

Comment: there were over 50k errors when i ran flutter analyze.  I created a new flutter project and had the same error.  my solution was to do flutter run from the terminal outside of vscode.  doing that cleared the errors in vscode and the emulator opened successfully.

Comment: Perhaps you have an old Flutter install somewhere that VSCode found?

Comment: I think it was a vscode issue.  I've bypassed it and moved to android studio and everything seems to be fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error, but it was always on my test folder.
This is what I did:

1. On your terminal, make sure you are in your project repository.
2. Run the `flutter pub get` command, it worked for me, may be you
   should try it too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have two different versions of the Flutter SDK on your machine? I wonder if one is being used by `flutter create` and the other for analysis.

If you're sure you only have one, please open an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) and attach [a log file](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#extension) for me to investigate.